# How do I make 'n' number of SKSpriteNode move in all direction continuously Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction, sknode

I want 'n' number of nodes keep moving in all direction continuously.
Below is how I coded

```
func spriteCollection(count : Int) -> [SKSpriteNode]{

    var spriteArray = [SKSpriteNode]()

    for _ in 0..<count {
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "node.png")

        //giving random position to sprites, 
        let x =  CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(((self.scene?.frame.width)! - sprite.size.width))))
        let y = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(((self.scene?.frame.height)! - sprite.size.height))))

        sprite.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
        spriteArray.append(sprite)
    }

    return spriteArray
}


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    //here if I pass more than 2, the nodes won't even get displayed sometimes
    let spriteCollection = spriteCollection(2)

    for sprite in spriteCollection{

       let blockOFaction = SKAction.runBlock({
            let x =  CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(((self.scene?.frame.width)! - sprite.size.width))))
            let y = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(((self.scene?.frame.height)! - sprite.size.height))))
            let action = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: x , y: y), duration: 2)
            print("moving to \(x,y)")
            action.speed = 3.0
            sprite.runAction(action)

        })
        let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)

        sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([blockOFaction, waitAction])))
        addChild(sprite)
    }
}
```

The nodes are moving randomly in all direction, but if I add more than 2 sprites, sometimes none of the sprites are visible(just a blank screen) and also I want to increase the number of sprites eventually. Here what I'm doing is, just passing the number of sprites I want(It cannot be increased eventually) So is there any other way to do it.  Could anyone please suggest me how can I achieve this..

Comment: What do you mean "move randomly in all direction"? Should each sprite have a direction and keep moving in that direction? Or should each sprite "wiggle" around? Sometimes up, sometimes left, right, down, etc...

Comment: Are you sure they are not drawing?  Perhaps they are just being rendered off your screen.  What is your scaleMode set to?  What is your scene size set to? how big is your node?  Why are you using self.scene? Is this class your gamescene class?  You should be using self then,

Comment: You can do `skView.showsNodeCount = true` inside you viewcontroller class to check how many nodes actually are created, to see if they are generated out of you screen. (Make sure to change your background-color, because the nodeCount text color is white!)

Comment: As I mentioned, Its not happening everytime, sometimes it doesn't display.

Comment: @Fogmeister yes I want each sprite to wiggle around

Comment: @Eric Yes actually node is added to screen, I can see the count in showsNodeCount, but nodes are not visible sometimes

Comment: @PruthviHariharan This code works completely fine for me. Except the fact that this  `let spriteCollection = spriteCollection(2)` generates error, but simply changing it to  `let sprites = spriteCollection(2)` solves the problem. If I recall correctly, I told you in one of your questions, that the scene and the view can have different sizes. So, in your view controller set the size of initial scene, and after each transition, set the size of a scene explicitly. Also, set the zPositions of nodes explicitly if you use `ignoresSiblingsOrder = true` (if overlapping can be an issue).

Comment: Yeah, I got your point and I set the  scene size in viewController, so where should I set the scene size explicitly after each transaction? Is it inside runBlock? and Should I set different  zPositions for each node?

Comment: @Whirlwind I have one more question, How do I make nodes add to scene one after the other? I mean at first I should have one node and later it should keep adding similar nodes. For this I have used NSTimer,but not sure whether its correct way to do it.                                                                  timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(Double(i), target: self, selector: "repeatAddingSprites", userInfo: nil, repeats: true), In repeatAddingSprites method I'm calling spritesCollection func and passing different  count each time. Please assist, I'm new to SpriteKit.

Comment: @PruthviHariharan You should set scene's size every time you create a new scene (before the actual transition - SKTransition). Not sure that I can answer you within one comment all about zPositions, but you set the zPosition of the nodes in that way, that they can't appear below other game elements.

Comment: @PruthviHariharan About NSTimer...Yeah, it is generally bad idea because NSTimer doesn't respect scene's or view's (or even node's) paused state, so you can run into issues eventually in some cases (if you don't implement custom "pause" feature). This is not the case with SKActions, and you can use them to spawn your nodes after certain time delay. Just create a sequence which will wait and spawn an enemy...

Comment: Ok, then I will not use NSTimer. Thanks for your suggestions. Really appreciate!